# OneNote - I don't want to sync to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, onenote

Is there a way to stop OneNote notes from automatically being saved to my OneDrive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't. The idea behind OneNote is to sync all the data from one device to another. You can choose to turn off your data plan/wifi when OneNote is opened to stop syncing or you can instead use Microsoft Office app to save your notes, they don't get automatically synced.